# Font size in Windows and Offce

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, ms-office, font-size

just got a bit messy with my font size in Windows. For example the vba in excel:

[font size in vba](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtkeS.png)

I've tried all settings in  “Control Panel->Personalize->Window Color->Advanced appearance settings”

[Advanced appearance settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLkbY.png)

It also appears in dialogue boxes from the Internet Explorer. The font is so small, that it is hard to read. Firefox and Chrome are fine.

[Dialogue boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQNbh.png)

Actually I don't know how it got to all this mess and I'll get more and more frustrated. 
But maybe someone knows the answer to get it back.

Already set the font setting in Windows to default. 
By the way I'm using Windows 7.

thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer.

Delete and reinstall the windows fonts.

http://withsteps.com/404/how-i-restored-my-windows-7-default-fonts.html